# ranlib Error using Alire and GNAT with ASFML

Tags: ada

i am learning how to use Alire using the Ada binding to SFML which is ASFML. So far I have downloaded
and installed ASFML using Alire and have successfully imported it into my test project. When I go to compile it, it does compile and bind but gets stuck on the Linker phase.

Here is the error:

```
gprbuild -d -PC:\Users\Amynu\testproj\testproj.gpr -XASFML_BUILD_MODE=optimize -XASFML_CONTRACTS=enabled -XASFML_STYLE_CHECKS=enabled -XASFML_RUNTIME_CHECKS=enabled -XASFML_COMPILE_CHECKS=enabled -XOS=Windows_NT -XTESTPROJ_BUILD_MODE=optimize -XTESTPROJ_CONTRACTS=disabled -XTESTPROJ_STYLE_CHECKS=disabled -XTESTPROJ_RUNTIME_CHECKS=disabled -XTESTPROJ_COMPILE_CHECKS=disabled
Compile
   [Ada]          testproj.adb
Bind
   [gprbind]      testproj.bexch
   [Ada]          testproj.ali
Link
   [link]         testproj.adb
c:/gnat/2021/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.1/ld.exe: C:\Users\Amynu\testproj\alire\cache\dependencies\asfml_2.5.2_b775db19\lib\libasfml.a: error adding symbols: archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gprbuild: link of testproj.adb failed
```

I have absolutely no idea what a "ranlib" is, I searched Alire but it's not a known crate or a library. I tried various options in Alire such as

```
alr with libranlib
```

and

```
alr get ranlib
```

To no avail. Is it an option within GNAT's command line? I did look into the GPR file for the project and that all looks alright. One the GPR's being auto generated by Alire when I build the project with

```
alr init --bin testproj
alr cd testproj
alr with libasfml
alr build
```

I did a Google search and found a lot of solutions connected to Unix and IBM(?) something about ranlib being outdated as most compilers use "rm" now? I couldn't find a solution to GNAT flagging the same error.

Am I just using an outdated audio library?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: "ranlib" is an OS tool that adds an index (a symbol look-up table) to an object-code library. On my Mac OS-X, "man ranlib" introduces it as: "ranlib - add or update the table of contents of archive libraries". The error message you display shows that the linker, "ld", expects "libasfml.a" to have such an index, and suggests using "ranlib" to create an index in "libasfml.a". This seems to be an error in building "libasfml.a", or in how that library is invoked in the building of your application. My impression is that explicitly invoking "ranlib" is usually not needed.

Comment: Does getting play_2048 crate (which depends on asfml) and building it with Alire work? Does cleaning ASFML compilation and rebuilding help?

Comment: And what if you change "for Library_Kind use "static";" to "for Library_Kind use "dynamic";" in asfml.gpr?

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188) and update the answer going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! That solved the problem. Now I am stuck with a loads of "undefined references to..." I actually went through all the source files and got rid of all the warnings by addIng Constant to most variable names. I am guessing it's looking for a dependency that is missing?

```
Build Libraries [gprlib] asfml.lexch [link library] libasfml.dll c:/gnat/2021/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.1/ld.exe: C:\Users\Amynu\testproj\alire\cache\dependencies\asfml_2.5.2_b775db19\obj\sf-audio-music.o:sf-audio-music.adb:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `sfMusic_createFromFile'
```

And about 15 lines under that with the same error type. After looking into it, I had a look a the lines of code the error were referring to and found the errors are referencing what look like external files? Is their a part of ASFML that didn't download with the library?

Comment: Sory, but -- *what* "solved the problem"?

Comment: Oh I forgot to say. Changing "static" to "dynamic"

Comment: Are you building your application using "alr build"?

Comment: I am yes, but I can also edit using GNAT Studio

Answer (score 0):

I scoured the code for the first linker error and found line it's referring to.

```
with Interfaces.C.Strings;

package body Sf.Audio.Music is
   use Interfaces.C.Strings;

   --//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   --/ Create a new music and load it from a file
   --/
   --/ @param Filename   Path of the music file to open
   --/
   --/ @return A new sfMusic object (NULL if failed)
   --/
   --//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   function CreateFromFile (Filename : String) return sfMusic_Ptr is
      function Internal (Filename : chars_ptr) return sfMusic_Ptr;
      pragma Import (C, Internal, "sfMusic_createFromFile");
      Temp : chars_ptr   := New_String (Filename);
      R    : sfMusic_Ptr := Internal (Temp);
   begin
      Free (Temp);
      return R;
   end CreateFromFile;
```

I cannot find the file it's trying to reference anywhere in the ASFML library. Was it left out?

So far, I have managed to successfully build ASFML in Alire with

```
alr get asfml
cd asfml
alr build asfml
```

This worked fine. Then I successfully imported into my project with

```
cd myproj
alr myproj with asfml
```

Again, do problems. Then I attempted to build it (after correcting the ranlib error) and I got the same load of linker errors. I don't understand why, as I successfully built the asfml library before I imported it wit Alire. Is it just a file I am missing, or do I have to explicitly tell the linker where the asfml file is?

Some of the errors.

```
Compile
   [Ada]          alicegame.adb
Build Libraries
   [gprlib]       asfml.lexch
   [link library] libasfml.dll
c:/gnat/2021/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.1/ld.exe: C:\Users\Amynu\alicegame\alire\cache\dependencies\asfml_2.5.2_b775db19\obj\sf-audio-music.o:sf-audio-music.adb:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `sfMusic_createFromFile'
c:/gnat/2021/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.1/ld.exe: C:\Users\Amynu\alicegame\alire\cache\dependencies\asfml_2.5.2_b775db19\obj\sf-audio-soundbuffer.o:sf-audio-soundbuffer.adb:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `sfSoundBuffer_createFromFile'
```

Comment: Try adding this to your project file. It should be inherited via the "with" to asfml.gpr, but may the change to dynamic libraries has broken something.   
  package Linker is
      for Linker_Options use
        ("-lcsfml-system", "-lcsfml-audio", "-lcsfml-network",
         "-lcsfml-audio", "-lcsfml-graphics", "-lcsfml-window",
         "-lasfml");
  end Linker;

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I attempted this but still got the same errors. I did check in the asmfl gpr and those exact lines of code are present. I think it's something the creators of the library need to look at. I was thinking about emailing them, the address is within the copyright comments in the source. Again thank you everyone for your aid I really do appreciate it. I might have to try another library like AdaSDL if I do not hear back.

Comment: You should open an issue in GitHub or use the Discussions tab: https://github.com/mgrojo/ASFML/issues https://github.com/mgrojo/ASFML/discussions